# django api deployed to google app engine error: 2005, "Unknown MySQL server host https://mythic-plexus-194517.appspot.com/products/

Tags: python, django, rest, google-app-engine, web-hosting

I'm trying to host a django-build api on google's app engine but i'm struggling to get it to work. This is the first time I'm deploying an app to production so apologies for the noob question.

I've deployed the app and all works at the base domain https://mythic-plexus-194517.appspot.com, however, when I go to /products endpoint where the relevant information in my db is posted, I hit (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'mythic-plexus-194517:europe-west1:giftwiz-api' (38)"). I do not hit this error when I run python manage.py runserver.

My app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: giftwiz_project.wsgi.application

libraries:

- name: django
  version: "latest"

- name: MySQLdb
   version: "latest"

env_variables:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'giftwiz_project.settings'
```

database config in settings.py:

```
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': 'mythic-plexus-194517:europe-west1:giftwiz-api',
            'NAME': 'products',
            'USER': 'xxxx',
            'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
            'PORT': '3306'
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'NAME': 'products',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('mysql_pass')
        }
    }
```

and urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from app import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'products', views.ProductViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.api_root),
]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am not very familiar with MySQL on GCP but are you sure `mythic-plexus-194517:europe-west1:giftwiz-api` is a correct hostname for your database? I would think it should look like an actual hostname or an ip address of the instance of your MySQL server. It doesn't seem right and the likely reason it works fine locally because there it's connecting to `127.0.0.1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `HOST` is wrong, it is missing `/cloudsql/` prefix. It should be `'/cloudsql/mythic-plexus-194517:europe-west1:giftwiz-api'`.